# Package Issue with Fsevents

Tags: npm, fsevents

[image]

System Version: MacOS Sonoma 14.3

Issue Description:
No errors were seen during 'npm install', but when running 'npm run dev', the following warnings and errors occurred:

What I've tried:

1. Following the provided location, I found the 'fsevents.node' file in the 'node_modules' directory, which appears as unreadable text in my VSCode editor.ChatGPT mentioned that the issue might be due to the 'rollup-plugin-inject' package encountering problems parsing the 'fsevents.node' file. However, I haven't explicitly installed 'rollup-plugin-inject' in my project; I only see its dependency in the 'package-lock.json' file through other packages.
2. I have already updated to the latest version of Node.js (version 20.11.0 LTS) on my computer, but the same error still occurs.

---

Due to this issue with the package, I am unable to successfully run 'npm run dev' to make changes to the project.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and how can it be resolved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're facing an issue related to the 'fsevents' package, which is a dependency often used in Node.js projects, especially on macOS for file watching. The error you're encountering could be related to the 'fsevents.node' file.

Here are some steps you can try to resolve the issue:

Remove 'node_modules' and 'package-lock.json':

Delete the 'node_modules' directory.
Delete the 'package-lock.json' file.
Clean npm cache:

Run the following commands in your terminal:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Reinstall dependencies:

Run the following commands:

```
npm install
```

Check for 'fsevents' version compatibility:

Ensure that the version of 'fsevents' in your 'package.json' or 'package-lock.json' is compatible with your Node.js version and the project's requirements.
Update 'npm' and 'node':

Ensure you are using the latest version of npm. Run:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

If you're not on the latest LTS version of Node.js, consider updating to the latest version.
Check for known issues:

Visit the GitHub repository or npm page for the packages involved ('fsevents', 'rollup-plugin-inject') and check for any open issues or discussions related to your problem.
Manual removal of 'fsevents.node':

Navigate to the 'node_modules' directory and manually remove the 'fsevents.node' file.
Run npm install again.
Check for peer dependencies:

Ensure that the packages in your project have the correct peer dependencies specified.
If the issue persists, it might be a good idea to temporarily disable 'fsevents' for development purposes. You can do this by running the following command:

```
npm install --no-save fsevents
```

This will prevent 'fsevents' from being installed, and your project may use a different file-watching mechanism. Keep in mind that some features related to file watching may not work as expected in this case.

Always make sure to back up your code before making significant changes, and consider consulting the documentation or community forums for the specific packages involved for additional guidance.

Comment: Hi @Mohamed Imran, I didn't originally install fsevents myself. I think it might have been brought into my node_modules folder because other packages are dependent on it. My current workaround is to remove the entire fsevents folder from my node_modules after running `npm i`. This allows me to successfully `npm run dev` for now, but it seems like the root issue hasn't been resolved. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node.js and npm, as well as clearing the cache. Anyway, thank you very much for your comprehensive response. It's good to know there are many ways to handle problems! Best.

Comment: You're welcome! It sounds like you've found a workaround for the issue by removing the 'fsevents' folder manually from the 'node_modules' directory. However, as you mentioned, this may not fully address the root cause of the problem.

Since you've already tried reinstalling Node.js and npm, as well as clearing the cache, and the issue persists, it might be related to compatibility or configuration problems within your project's dependencies, Or else try deleting node related folders in c:/users/your-user-name/appdata/roaming and again do npm install